# delete webmin or not? any good reasons to keep it sitting on server?

Tags: webmin

I'm running ubuntu server. And during original set-up I installed webmin thinking it would be useful in some way. But after a month, I never even logged in. I tend to edit config files myself, and feel it's better to get familiar with txt files and their syntax.

What is your take on this?

Why would you leave webmin on the server? (p.s. I imagine in my case it's useless potential security hole)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to get used to edit the config files by hand, and know more about the server configuration then go ahead and delete it.

FWIW, I have never used webmin or other app like that and lived happily.

Comment: apt-get --purge remove webmin - :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat. The only reason I see for a competent Linux administrator to leave one of those panel applications in place is as a training ground for the less experienced - usually windows centric - administrators to get use to administering Linux boxes.

If this is not a concern in your environment I would delete it.